# What is the 'y' axis in normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have this graph for questions on normal distribution:

**Question 1.** What is the probability that a participant selected at random will require more than 500 hours to complete the program?

[image]

Answer is $0.5$ by looking at the graph.

**Question 2.** What is the "probability" that a candidate selected at random will take between 500 and 650 hours to complete the training program?

[image]

The answer is $0.4332$.

Now, my question is where is the probably density function i.e. Y axis? How do I draw the Y-axis? Is "probably density function" same as just probability that I am finding?

I would like if someone can draw that Y-axis and answer it using Y-axis. So, I can understand its use.

Comment: Yes, the $y$ axis is the value of the probably density function. The probability is a different thing, it is the area below the curve for the studied interval. The [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) is closely related with the probability density function. Its tables are usually used to solve this types of problems and in the graphic of that function, reading the $y$ axis is equivalent to look at the corresponding statistical table.

Comment: I don't get it how its different. How can I create a y-axis with values? Okay, is the peak always $0.4$ as I am seeing in most figures?

Comment: For **standard** normal $(\mu = 0, \sigma = 1)$ the maximum point of the density curve is above $0$ at $1/\sqrt{2\pi} =  0.3989423\approx 0.4.$ For other notmal distributions, different heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Areas in graphs in the Question are not to scale and may be confusing. (Red Z with arrows is inappropriate.) Vertical scales are missing.

(2) $$P(500 \le X \le 650) = P\left(\frac{500-500}{100}\le
\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{650 - 500}{100}\right)\\
=P(0 \le  Z \le 1.5) =  0.4332.$$

On original scale of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 500, \sigma = 100),$ the desired area is between the vertical dashed lines.

[image]

On standard normal scale:

[image]

---

**Addenda:(1)** The area under every density function must be $1.$
Except for a linear transformation, all normal density functions are the same shape. 
Under any normal density curve, the area between $\mu \pm \sigma$ is about 68% of the entire area. (As the horizontal scale, indicated by $\sigma,$ increases, the height of the curve decreases.)

- For the standard normal distribution the interval $\mu \pm \sigma$ has length $2$ and the distribution reaches a maximum height of about 0.4.
- In $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 500, \sigma = 100)$ the interval $\mu \pm \sigma$ amounts to $(400, 600$ of length 200 (100 times as long as for standard normal), and the maximum height is about 0.004 ($\frac{1}{100}$th as tall).

**(2)** *Finding the probability that a standard normal random variable
$Z$ lies in the the interval* $[0, 1]:$ From printed tables, we know
that $P(0 \le  Z \le 1) = 0.3413.$ Here is a rough idea how that
probability can be computed.

In the figure below the interval $[0, 1]$ is divided into ten
sub-intervals, each of width $0.1$ by points at $0.0, 0.1, 0.2, \dots, 0.9, 1.0.$ The respective centers of these intervals are
at points $0.05, 0.15, \dots, 0.95,$ respectively. A rectangle
is erected above each interval; its height is such that the
center of the top crosses the standard normal density curve.

[image]

For example, the first rectangle has height $\phi(0.05) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-.5(0.05^2} =  0.3984439$ and width $0.1.$
So the area of the first rectangle is about $0.03984.$ The second rectangle has width $0.1$ and is a little shorter, and so on.

One can show that the total area of all ten of these tall, thin
rectangles is $0.3414$ to four decimal places. Of course, the
combined area of the rectangles is not *exactly* the same as
$P(0 \le Z \le 1) = 0.3413$ because the straight-line tops
of the rectangles do not exactly match the standard normal density curve. But the approximation is very good.  [Computation in R.]

```
w = .1;  z = seq(.05, .95, by=.1);  h = dnorm(z)
w*h
[1] 0.03984439 0.03944793 0.03866681 0.03752403 0.03605270
[6] 0.03429439 0.03229724 0.03011374 0.02779849 0.02540591
sum(w*h)
[1] 0.3414456
```

If we used 100 rectangles each with width 0.01, then their sum would be 0.3413, matching the probability given in printed tables, correct to more than four decimal places.

There is no way to use individual *points* to find $P(0 \le  Z \le 1)$ because there are infinitely many points. But we can find this probability to any desired degree of accuracy by using sufficiently many sufficiently thin rectangles. Nowadays, we have somewhat
better ways of computing standard normal probabilities, but the
original printed tables were made using almost exactly the same
rectangle method described above. (Imagine rooms full of people slaving away at mechanical calculators for many hours.)

Comment: Thanks. But where am I using this density 'Y' axis? What's its purpose? It seems I am only using area under the curve to get answers.

Comment: Often you _are_ only using a normal curve to find an area (probability). But the vertical axis is important, it changes as the scale (indicated by $\sigma)$ changes. See my addendum at the end for an example.

Comment: If I add up all the probability densities in (2) from $x = 500$ to $x = 650$, I should get my answer right? (without using any tables). What's the density is, why not say it just probability? Thank you!

Comment: Technically, you can't add up probability densities. (There are infinitely many of them.) You _can_ approximate the area under the curve by many rectangles (small bases, heights just tall enough to reach the curve) and adding their areas .[You are asking good and important questions. If you're familiar with calculus, this is how the Riemann integral is defined.]

Comment: I see but suppose if I could add them at each point of $x$, that's what's really happening theoretically, right? I am just trying to relate with the use of probability density function $f(x)$.

Comment: @user963241 :You are on the right track about summing many values to get probabilities under the normal curve, but you have to sum areas of _rectangles._ See my second Addendum.